# Encoding problems with Zend Framework 2 (ZF2)

Tags: php, zend-framework, encoding, zend-framework2, zend-translate

I have a problem to display a translation with the right encoding...

Instead of displaying "Olá mundo!" appears "OlÃ¡ mundo!"

I could solve my problem using utf8_decode.

But if you use another language that would be a problem...

https://github.com/carloschea/ZF2-Translate-Test

Comment: It works fine on NGINX, so you are probably facing some awkward evil.  One thing I remember encountering, was a client who had AddDefaultCharset utf-8 in their apache config that was absolutely wrecking everything.  Strangely enough, removing that and restarting the web server, fixed things. http://imgur.com/os37qUh

Comment: Was that it? Let me know, I can mark it up as an answer -- thought I had :/

Comment: It was yes! Installed again apache, and everything returned to normal!!!!